# How to set value for button when auto create button

Tags: python, tkinter

I use for loop to create button, but I don't know set value for button, when I click that button I can get the value its.

In my code I show 3 button with name in list color. I want when I click any button, it will print with the color which you choose, but my code just show the red color when I click any button

Please help me this issue. Thank you

```
color = ['red','green', 'blue']
def createbutton():
    for col in color:    
        Button(win, text= col +' button' , bg = 'green', command= lambda c=col.index(col): print(color[c])).grid(row=color.index(col), column = 0) 

win = Tk()
win.geometry('750x1000')
createbutton()
win.mainloop()
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems like you just misspelled `color.index(col)`.
Instead you wrote `col.index(col)`.
This is the complete code:

```
color = ['red','green', 'blue']
def createbutton():
    for col in color:
        Button(win, text= col +' button' , bg = 'green', command= lambda 
c=color.index(col): print(color[c])).grid(row=color.index(col), column = 0)

win = Tk()
win.geometry('750x1000')
createbutton()
win.mainloop()
```

You can also make some changes as

- use `.pack()` instead of `.grid()`, as you just place one button after another,
- make the background of the button same as the color name `bg=col`
  Hope this helps!